# Rails: How to have dynamic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, polymorphic-associations

I'll use an example to explain what behaviour I would like to achieve.

If you had a project management app and you added a task, but not all the contributors are users of the app.
So when you adding contributors to the task you can enter a user name or email address.

Here is the part that I'm finding a little tricky. The `task` model has many contributors which are linked through the `user` model, but from this point on I want to achieve 2 things.

1. Store the non members email(this would obviously be quite simple)
2. If that email address was to create an account it would then link that user to the task and remove the temporally saved email.

This way, when that user creates an account all the related tasks will already be associated with their email.

Is this something that i could achieve with a polymorphic association? or is there something else I should be looking at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part which involves polymorphic associations is many `tasks` having many `contributors`.

There are many ways to achieve the other functionality that you desire.

I would probably store the temporary email address by creating a new `contributor` record without other the fields such as a `password`. When the user actually signs up, I would use a `first_or_create` method to complete setup of the user account.

This removes the need for storing temporary emails and transferring task ownership. The same `id` used to link a `contributor` to a `task` before they sign up is the same one used after they sign up.

Comment: I'm using devise which I'm pretty sure validate the uniqueness of a email address on sign up, so a user will be a contributor on many projects and many task within that project tasks. could I have a column that stores a email when there is no user to related to then when the emails signs up I search contributors table and link them up? basically creating a contributor_id that can be linked to a user_id later?

Comment: Sorry I'm just getting back to you. To answer "Could I have a column that stores a email when there is no user to related to then when the emails signs up I search contributors table and link them up?" Yes, Devise may need to be configured to create these `contributor` records with only an email but this pertains to how you validate records using methods such as `before_create`. I was suggesting that you either have a `contributor_id` or `user_id`, not both. The `contributor` table can contain complete records (people who have signed up) and incomplete records (only containing an email)

Comment: When the person actually signs up, use `first_or_create`. This will update an incomplete record with a password and other information, if the email address already exists. More info on first_or_create http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-first_or_create]